# Isomorphic graphs + alpha

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Which of the following graphs are isomorphic ?

I. 4 vertices A,B,C and D are positioned to form a square with side AD missing.
i.e, AB,BC and CD are the sides and they are perpendicular.

II. 4 vertices E,F,G and H are positioned similarly as A,B,C and D respectively, 
but the linesegment that connects the vertices are different. They are EG, GF,FH.
EG and FH "looks like" they intersect, but no point is defined there.

III. 4 points J,K,L and M in that order, are colinear on a straight line.

My claim is this.  I and III are obviously isomorphic, but I have a problem with I and II not being isomorphic.

The number of vertices match, and the number of linesegments match, too.  So If I define a function f such that

f(A) = E, f(B) = G, f(C) = F, f(D) = H, then
f(AB) = EG, f(BC) = GF, f(CD) = FH.

So there is a bijection.

A is adjacent to B while E is adjacent to G, B is adjacent to C while G is adj, ... etc.

So they have to be isomorphic. What am I doing wrong?

Another thing.

I would like to be able to use symbols such as sigma, or integration, or limits,... etc.
Where do I go to learn how to do this ?

Comment: Formulas: If you know (La)TeX, just write formulas between dollar signs like you'd ordinarly do. Otherwise read the tutorial in [this question on the meta site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For your last question, you can start [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your descriptions, all three graphs are isomorphic, and you're not doing anything wrong.

The fact that some lines in the *drawing* of a graph intersect is *by definition* not part of the graph itself -- it's just an incidental feature of one one chooses to *show* the graph on paper, just as the slopes and lengths of the lines that represent edges don't matter.